# Selecting an element from the jquery POST data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been trying to fetch the result of a php page after sending a post request to the page itself. I want to fetch the data after the post request succeeded and get the content of the `div` element with `id` result. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $.post("test.php",
        {
            name: "valid"
        },
        function(data, status) {

        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div id="result">
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        if($_POST['name'] == 'valid') {
            echo 'You are a valid user!';
        }
    }

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I submit the button regardless of what is written in the textbox I should get the `Your a valid user` message from the `test.php` I want to get this message in the result page and display it in the current page without reloading the page. Since the result page content is saved in `data` variable I don't know how to select an element which is contained in a variable instead of the current page itself. We can do `$("div#result").text()` for the current page. But how should I do it for the html content stored in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Just give your `data` variable as second parameter to jQuery like this:

```
$('#result', data).text()
```

Not tested but should work.

**Update:**

I don't know why but this will only work when your element you want to find is wrapped with another element within your body tag. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xf32L5uj/

Comment: I don't understand why, but if you wrap all your content in your `<body>`-tag in another `<div>`-tag jQuery recognizes your div correctly.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you mentioned in the last comment? What's wrong with this code? I have checked jQuery documentation and it has been said that second parameter of jQuery method can be content of a html contained in a specific variable. But it does not work as intended.

Comment: See my last update. I attached a fiddle which demonstrates the behaviour